# ng-repeat not working in UIKIT dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uikit

i have uikit dropdown template in which i am trying add ng-reapet but drop down not working.

guys please help .....

```
 <div class="uk-button-dropdown" uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}">
     <button class="md-btn">Click me <i class="material-icons">&#xE313;</i></button>
         <div class="uk-dropdown">
             <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown">

                 <li ng-repeat="item in locationName">
                     <a href="">{{item}}</a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
```

module

```
var addlocationModule = angular.module('addLocationApp', ['ngDialog']);    
addlocationModule.controller('addLocationController', function ($scope, $http, $window, ngDialog) {


    $scope.initialize = function(alllocation,loggedInEmployee) 
    {
            $scope.alllocations = alllocation;
            $scope.loggedInEmployee = loggedInEmployee;

            $scope.locationName = [];
            $scope.alllocations.forEach(function(resource) {
            $scope.locationName.push(resource.title);
            });


    }

    $scope.addLocations = function() {
          $http.post('/addLocationName',$scope.location).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if(response.data.status){
              $scope.alllocations.push(response.data.location);
              $scope.location.name="";
              $scope.location.description="";
              }
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
          })
    }
    });
```

Comment: call `$scope.initialize` function inside `.then`

Comment: thank you but it is already has been called in & i already have a data. here i have shown only portion of .html file

Comment: don't call it from html. call it inside the ` $scope.addLocations` function after `$scope.location.description=""` line

Comment: sure let me  try that ..

Comment: OOps thats also not working!!! :(

Comment: can you provide a plnkr

Comment: wish i could ... as of now i cant sorry......    i did in simple html n .js file it is working but with this using  uk-button-dropdown ui-kit component it is not working many angualrjs directives are not working.

Comment: 3/4 guys are working on this from past 4/5 days but no suceess

Answer (score 0):

you should add ng-repeat in ul tag

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown" ng-repeat="item in locationName">
    <li>
        <a href="">{{item}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i think it'll help you.

Comment: thank you but still it is not working.... UIKIt causing some problem not able to figure it out !!